# Create Tooltip with dynamic message on tab(tabview) in JSF

Tags: jquery, jsf, primefaces

I have to create tooltip for tab with dynamic value. I have tried static and dynamic way to create tooltip but it does'nt work for me and it is returning null. Please suggest some option thanks in advance.

jquery code

```
$(document).ready(
$('tab0').click(function(){
    showtext(); 
});
function showtext() {
    document.getElementById("tooltiptext").style.visibility = 'visible';
}
```

xhtml code(JSF)

```
<p:tabView id="specialistTabsId" cache="false"                                   
 onTabShow="if(focusFirstEleInTab){setFocustForFirstField(index);}
 else{focusFirstEleInTab=true;}"
 activeIndex="#{specialistViewManager.activeTabIndex}"
 widgetVar="specialistTabsWidget" scrollable="true">
    <p:ajax event="tabChange" listener="#{specialistViewManager.tabChange}" />
        <p:tab id="tab0" title="#{pprmsgs.persProfile_tab}" titletip="titletip">
           <div class="panel-container">
                <ui:include src="/pages/ppr/common/specialist/personalProfile.xhtml" />                                              
                   <div class="clearFix"></div>
           </div>
           <p:tooltip for="tab0" value="tooltip show"/>
           </p:tab>
          <div class="tooltip">
              <span id="tooltiptext" class="tooltiptextstyle">blah</span>
          </div>
     </p:ajax>
   </p:tabView>
```

Comment: $('tab0') is a invalid selector; check the jquery docs and also check the real ID via browser dev tools

Comment: I have change it to $('#tab0') but still there is no luck

Comment: Is it possible to call function on titletip attribute in tab

Comment: did you check the real ID in browser dev tools?

Comment: I checked but there is no Id only way to search with class. It is part of iframe

Comment: @tandraschko can we assign dialog box value to some constant using jQuery